# Using shared memory and semaphores with multiple clients

Tags: c, client-server, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm working with C on Linux. I need to build two programs that communicate using shared memory and semaphores.

One of the programs must serve as a server (only one at a time) and the other as a client (any number at a time). The communication should follow this pattern:

```
 Client1 -> Server (Client1 writes to ShM, Server reads it)  
 Client1 <- Server  
 Client2 -> Server  
 Client2 <- Server
```

I know how to use shared memory and semaphores between two processes but I don't know how to use them if an undefined number of processes want to communicate.
I thought about using a shared memory block for each client but i would have to exchange keys and notify the server of a new client. So this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use just a single block of shared memory for all clients that means at any given time, only one client can communicate with the server which can be a performance/security issue.  What if one client grabs the semaphore and never releases it.

If all clients are trusted and performance isn't an issue then your clients need to grab the semaphore and if they can't they can either block or spin on it.  Say you initialized the semaphore to 1, then each client will try to atomic down() it using something like test_and_set().  If test_and_set() returned 1, that means the operation succeeded and the client can communicate with the server.  If it failed, then the client can spin on the value till it becomes 1 again and then try again.

This solution is the bare minimum that you can use.  It suffers from the issues I mentioned above and also causes clients to spin (wasting cpu), does not gurantee fairness, starvation, etc.  You may be better off using mutexes on which you can actually go to sleep.

Comment: Ok I'm using one shared memory and 3 semaphores (clsem 1, sersem 0, anssem 0) to make the request-answer protocol possible.